# Removing the fancy lighting effect in beamer enumerate bullets

Tags: beamer, enumerate, bullets

Beamer bullets using enumerate have this cutesy lighting effect that I guess is meant to make the bullets seem 3D. In fact, they are simply hard to read, as the pic below illustrates.

[image]

Is there any way to make the bullets have a flat background color, i.e., removing the "lighting" effect? I scoured the manual for this, but I don't really know what a good keyword would be.   Thanks!

Comment: After 53 questions, you should really know how to add a MWE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The image you show is not the default behaviour of beamer, but rather a modification done by the `rounded` inner theme. If you don't like it, use another inner theme instead, for example the `circles` inner theme:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\useinnertheme{circles}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}
\item test
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]